# how to calculate overlap length between two points array in python?

Tags: python, algorithm

Suppose there are 2 arrays. Every element in the array is short line contains start position and end position.

```
a1 = [[0,1],[3,6],[7,9]]
a2 = [[2,6],[0,1]]
```

In this example, a1[0] is same with a2[1], the overlap length is 1. a1[1] and a2[0] has overlap length of 3. The total result is 4.
Are there any way to achieve this method easily?

Comment: Doesn't a1[1] and a2[0] has overlap of 3?

Comment: @TomRon Sorry I make a mistake, the overlap is 3 between a1[1] and a2[0]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.product` to generate all interval pairs and then calculate the overlap for each pair. Two intervals overlap if one starts before the second ends.

```
import itertools

overlap=0
for  x, y in itertools.product(a1, a2):
     max_start = max(x[0], y[0])
     min_end = min(x[1], y[1])
     overlap += max(0, min_end-max_start)
```

Comment: Ouch! As the number of items in a and b increase you are doing a*b comparison sets. OK if you can afford that.

Comment: That's true, that's the simplest solution.  If you sort the lists you achieve a more efficient solution

Answer (score 1):

There is an ambiguity in the problem statement: Can intervals in the same set overlap each other, and if so, do we double count the overlap of those intervals with an interval in the other set or not?

Anyway, The brute-force approach will take O(N^2) time, which may be fine depending on how large the sets are. But it can be improved to O(N*logN) by sorting the two sets by the starting points. If overlapping within the same set is not allowed, you can simply go from left two right, keeping track of the last intervals in each set that overlap each other. If overlapping within the same set is allowed, you can keep a heap of intervals of the first set of which the endpoints have not been reached, and iterate over the second set

In the case of non-overlapping intervals within the same set, the code will be something like this:

```
a1 = [[0,1],[3,6],[7,9]]
a2 = [[2,6],[0,1]]


a1.sort(key = lambda x: x[0])
a2.sort(key = lambda x: x[0])

i1 = 0
i2 = 0

overlapping = 0

while i1 < len(a1) and i2 < len(a2):
    # start and end of the overlapping
    start = max(a1[i1][0], a2[i2][0]) 
    end = min(a1[i1][1], a2[i2][1])

    overlapping += max(0, end-start)

    # move the interval that ends first to the next interval in the same set
    if a1[i1][1] < a2[i2][1]:
        i1 += 1
    else:
        i2 += 1

print(overlapping)
```

Comment: Ah, after reading Toms answer, I was about to suggest similar :-)